# how to deal with multi label classfication in LSTM model in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am doing a multi label classfication(4 labels) task, specially a text classfication. I get 1000 txts and every one has 50 word and a labels, each word is embedded 100 dimension, and I use pytorch. I have a question,
every txt has diffentent length, e.g. ten words, five words or eight word. I first embedding the words into 100 dimension and I know LSTM is Sequence length independent. So I can deal the every txt success, but how can I deal with many txts at the same time??

When I deal with many txts, I just pad the txt to the same length(20len), and I train torch.nn.LSTM in batch_first, the input is (1000, 20, 100) and output is (1000, 20, 100), and the labels is (1000), I use crossEntropy...I know it is wrong, so how to do it

Comment: no have 50 word, just different number words

Answer (score -1):

You can see a concrete example [here](https://medium.com/@sonicboom8/sentiment-analysis-with-variable-length-sequences-in-pytorch-6241635ae130) and [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-preparation-variable-length-input-sequences-sequence-prediction/)...